# PHPUnit test suite include path

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Using phpunit and I am having some trouble with include paths, not for phpunit itself, but for my code and tests directory.

I have the following code structure:

```
Application
  -StringCalculator.php

tests
  -StringCalculatorTest.php
```

Inside my StringCalculatorTest.php i have a require statement:

```
require_once('../StringCalculator.php');
```

Running `phpunit StringCalculatorTest.php` from  inside the tests folder works perfectly.

However, when i then introduce a phpunit.xml configuration file in the root directory i.e.

```
Application
  -StringCalculator.php

tests
  -StringCalculatorTest.php

phpunit.xml
```

the include path is screwed.  I have to replace the require_once to

```
require_once('StringCalculator.php');
```

What is the correct way to set include paths between the application and the test directory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best place to set your PHP include path is in your bootstrap file.  Usually, your `phpunit.xml` file will include a bootstrap attribute:

```
<phpunit backupGlobals="true"
     backupStaticAttributes="false"
     bootstrap="bootstrap.php"
     cacheTokens="true"
     colors="true"
     ... and so on ...
</phpunit>
```

Then in your bootstrap file you can set include paths, include important files, etc..

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../my/sources');
```

The config file is covered in [Appendix C](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html) of the PHPunit docs.

**EDIT:** Link updated

Answer (score 9):

I know the question already been answer
This answer is for future visitor

According to phpunit documentation, u can use `includePath` directive in your `phpunit.xml` for your inclusion path

```
<php>
  <includePath>/path/to/ur/project</includePath>
</php>
```

Answer (score 3):

First, I don't get how `require_once('../StringCalculator.php');` works, it should rather be: `require_once('../Application/StringCalculator.php');`.

Then, slashingweapon answer is good and it's the best IMO, however if you don't want that much trouble, you can specify your `require_once` to start from the directory of the current file:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '../Application/StringCalculator.php');
```