# Configuring phpStorm and XML for phpUnit 7 (remote) Coverage

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm, code-coverage

I'm playing for a week with phpUnit.

I'm slowly going forward with documentation at:

- https://phpunit.readthedocs.io

At this point I'm at code Coverage. I've managed to generate small test **--coverage-html** (via console). I want everything to work via phpStorm.

I'm struggling with inclusion paths. I can see errors in console, but these aren't to helpful at all.

**This is how my console output looks like:**

[image]

**This is the only place I use this file in**

[image]

**This is how folder structure for tested and displayed (in console) file looks like**

```
|- dir:Boostrap
|- dir:Coverage
|- dir:Database
|- dir:Interfaces
|- dir:Methods
|---- file: BasicCalculations.php (line 3 inclusion)
|- dir:Tests
|---- file:DataDisplayingTest.php (file that I'm testing)
|---- dir:Data Providers
|-------- file:BasicCalculationDataProvider.php (line 4 inclusion)
```

**What I've tried/What I've made so far**

- [Cannot find PHPUnit in include path phpstorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310259/cannot-find-phpunit-in-include-path-phpstorm) (I'm not doing this via composer/vendor so this is not helping, my remote machine is for all the debugging, calculations etc).
- [PHPUnit test suite include path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129993/phpunit-test-suite-include-path) - this gave me idea to play around with bootstrap file, where I've included all the required files, but again this worked only via manually running tests in console - I want to make it work in phpStorm remotely.

  - [PHPUnit's whitelist and blacklist seem to be ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29675798/phpunits-whitelist-and-blacklist-seem-to-be-ignored) . At this point situation looks like this
    without **processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true"** I've got no inclusion error, but I got just more errors after that:
    [image]
    It looks like it's trying to work as console gets green for a moment and I've got the Coverage panel now, but I bet this errors shouldn't be there. I can't be sure If coverage report is being displayed correctly at all.
  - [PHPUnit error "Failed to open stream: No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060119/phpunit-error-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory) - I've tried the DIR as You can see,
  - https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/1932 - this helped me a bit, now I know I can/have to import xml, and this way I don’t have to generate coverage report remotely via ssh

**This is how my phpunit.xml looks like:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="phpunit.xsd"
         cacheResult="true"
         verbose="true">

    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory>/var/www/html/phpUnit</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <php>
         <includePath>/var/www/html/phpUnit</includePath>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

I've played around with directory/incluedPath, tried variation like:

```
 - /var/www/html/phpUnit
 - /var/www/html/phpUnit/
 - .
 - ./
 - <file>pointed/tested/file/here/</file>
```

I'm working with:

- phpStorm
- phpUnit 7.x Remotely
- php 7.x  Remotely
- xdebug Remotely

To be more clear:

- what am I doing wrong?
- how can I deal with inclusions problems?
- what is causing all this inclusion path problems?

Comment: I think that I've made some proggress with: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041254/phpunit-coverage-what-is-the-difference-between-adduncoveredfilesfromwhitelist) . This: `<whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="false">` seems to remove all the errors on last line and even got coverage with percentage of code covered. Will test it more most likely tommorow.

Comment: Hi, take a look to this specific documentation on how to configure PHPStorm and PHPUnit. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/enabling-php-unit-support.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering I've managed to fix everything and surprisingly these weren't phpStorm based issues - will write it all in free time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve manage to solve all the problems I had. I’ve used some of the informations provided in the links I’ve pointed above.

First of all

**Include errors**

PhpUnit xml uses directive includePath, which in my case looked like this:

```
<php>
      <includePath>/var/www/html/phpUnit</includePath>
</php>
```

Generally at this point the problem is with… existence of includePath in xml file. This attribute changes the inclusion path.

So lets say that You got project structure like that:

```
- dir: Classes
–- dir: A
–-- file: A.php class: A (extends B)
–- dir: B
–-- file: B.pphp class: B
-file: index.php
```

So from the look of file A.php You would need to include B.php like that:
../B/B.php

Since the working directory is

```
/var/www/html/phpUnit/Classes/
```

But now since You’ve set up inclusion path to:

```
var/www/html/phpUnit
```

File A, tries to load file B from the perspective of phpUnit folder, and it’s kinda looking for file in:

```
var/www/html
```

Not having this directive is not solving the problem as phpUnit seems to use some other default path.

I’ve solved this problem by changing the way I include files in project:

Just instead using:

```
include_once '../Interfaces/BasicCalculationsInterface.php';
```

I’ve started doing it like this:

```
include_once __DIR__.'/../Interfaces/BasicCalculationsInterface.php';
```

This way:

- Single files tests work fine
- Project itself works fine
- phpStorm detects methods, classes etc in included file
- Group tests work well too

**Writing file index.html permission denied**

I’ve stumbled upon this problem as well. This actually is some kind of phpStorm issue, which I don’t know how to solve permanently but I’ve dealt with it for the xml file from which I can run all my tests.

Basically phpStorm added some default configurations for executed tests.

In menu go to

**Run/Edit Configurations**

Take a look at field **Test Runner options**.

In my case phpStorm added

```
--coverage-html /
```

Everything would be fine, but I use Ubuntu on laptop as remote host, and phpStorm tries this way to create files in **/** directory for which there is no writing permission. Changing this to some writeable folder or removing this line solved the problem.

And that’s all, this is how my xml file looks like at this point (just in case someone would like to have something to look at)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="phpunit.xsd"
         verbose="true">
    <filter>
        <whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="false">
            <directory suffix=".php">/var/www/html/phpUnit</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-clover" target="/var/www/html/phpunit/coverage.xml" lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70"/>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="/var/www/html/phpUnit/phpStormCoverageTest" lowUpperBound="35"
             highLowerBound="70"/>
    </logging>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="allTests">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">/var/www/html/phpUnit/Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

**Preview of working html/phpStorm coverage**
[image]

[image]